# what is the alternate of tree view control in MAC.

Tags: cocoa

I am a beginner in MAC, so please let me know the alternate of tree control in MAC, to explore data and selection of files from that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are looking for `NSOutlineView`.  It is a view that allows hierarchical displays (lists of indented elements with disclosure triangles, etc.).

Comment: ok thanks. Multiple selection is possible in outline view, just like tree control with checkbox in MFC

Comment: It's a subclass of `NSTableView` which can do multiple-selection, yes.

Comment: thanks kevin.  Do u have any sample code or link to help my development

Comment: Search Apple's site for examples; there is at least this one: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/NewsReader/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003985

Comment: using NSOutlineview, i can create file explorer, but how can show the icon along with file name.